# Adjust timeout settings on ubuntu backup (dejadup)

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I use deja-dup front-end (default backup application in Ubuntu since 12.04 or so?) to execute a remote backup.  Recently, the backup seems to run fine, transferring files successfully to the remote backup server, but when running the "verifying backup" stage, it always ends now with the error "Timeout was reached".  Is there some way to adjust the time out settings or otherwise work around this error? (I don't see anything in the front end, but perhaps adjusting duplicity settings from the command line some how?).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to directly configure custom duplicity arguments in deja-dup. There is a [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/700570) reported though which discusses this issue.

As a workaround what you can do is to change the default global duplicity values in the following file

```
sudo vim /usr/share/pyshared/duplicity/globals.py
```

The two options you probably want to increase to overcome your timeout issue are the following

```
# network timeout value
timeout = 30

# number of retries on network operations
num_retries = 5
```

Please note though that those values will be overwritten whenever there is a new version of duplicity installed.

Comment: To add to this: On my machine (Ubuntu 20.04, duplicity version 0.8.11.1612-1), I found the configuration file in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/globals.py`. I found it using the following command, which searches the whole system for all files and folders containing the word "duplicity": `sudo find / -iname *duplicity*`